# How to handle sqlite in iCloud

Tags: iphone, sqlite, icloud

I'm having a **Sample.sqlite** database in my app and can you help me on how to save the Sample.sqlite of my app in iCloud and how to download that SQLite file from iCloud and handling in our app

Thanks for any suggestions.

---

I'm trying implement ur idea of saving closed database in iCloud,but it's returning following error

> **Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted" UserInfo=0x299bb0 {NSDescription=Unable to rename '/var/mobile/Applications/98E15712-5A98-439B-BED1-82A5A548CB15/Sample.app/Sample.sqlite' to '/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/TV8M2M4B6L~com~companyName~sam/Documents/Sample.sqlite'.}**

**//MyCode**

```
BOOL isCopiedToiCloud = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:localUrl destinationURL:iCloudURL error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [iOS App Programming Guide:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1)

> Use Core Data if you want to store live databases in iCloud; do not
>   use SQLite.

When Apple state this clearly not to do something, I think it's advice worth following.

The important word here is "live." If you close your connection to the SQLite database and then save a *copy* to iCloud I think you should be okay.

Comment: Thank you.....But After developing the whole app with sqlite database client asked iCloud feature......is there any alternative? please suggest me

Comment: If you just want a checkbox item -- supports iCloud -- you can do it; I've edited my answer. But it's not going to be as seamless as using Core Data.

Comment: thank you Stephen.....I'll come back after successfully implement  your suggestion

Comment: Hi,Can you provide any sample for how to implement core data to store database in iCloud or any link(except developer.apple.com)....Thanks in adavance

Comment: @Srivinas can you plesse help me how to save your database in iCloud.I am not getting understood which tutorial to follow or how to proceed with iCloud integration.I also need to do the same thing.I tried to follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1 link but it is for UIDocument.Please help me.